# npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported

Tags: node.js, npm

I received this warning message:

> npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported

when I ran the command:

```
$ npm i adaro --save
```

What does this warning mean? What is an optional dependency? Is it serious? How do I get rid of that warning?

Comment: One of dependency module's optional dependency is probably not supported on your system. Quite likely fsevents which is optional dep of chokidar. try `npm install fsevents` if it fails you know it is the module that failed to install. It's only for OSX so you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 13):

The warning message is just a warning message and not an error. It does not affect the application.

It is a log message that an [optional dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#optionaldependencies) could not be installed because it is not supported/needed on your current platform/cpu-arch. For example the package `fsevents` is often used as optional dependency but fails on any system that is not a Mac.

To show what package is throwing this message, run

```
$ npm install --verbose
```

This warning could also be triggered by packages having an engine set to something lower than what you are running. You can try

```
$ pm_config_engine_strict=false npm install
```

to get around this

Comment: Was this a solution? i keep thinking my project is failing because im trying to work on this project that was originally created in mac os